# How can I handle the login alert?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests

How can I close or How can I enter the UserId and password and click on Login?

[This the alert code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr65V.png)

[how the alert looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPX88.png)

Please help me in handling this alert

Comment: Can  you provide the actual HTML from the page you're trying to automate? Also show us what you've got so far.

Comment: please give proper context .the question is not clear .add relevant code and not images

Comment: This alert is opening in new tab, No HTML script is loaded

Comment: Which browser you are using /

Comment: Chrome 59 onward they have depreciated this functionality in there browser .

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this in JAVA:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@www.domain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :-

String Password = URLEncoder.encode("pass");

String UserName= URLEncoder.encode("UserName");

String url = String.format("http://%s:%s@xyz", UserName, Password);

In this %s is variable which pass to url in form of parameter .

You can refer this url also https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [desiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)?

This should close alert while in automated window

```
DesiredCapabilities dC= DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
dC.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT)
```